# Write in Interval Form

Tags: real-numbers

x² - 5x + 6 < 0 .
x² - 2x - 3x + 6 < 0 .
x (x-2) - 3 (x-2) < 0 .
(x-3) (x-2) < 0 .
x<2 & x<3
So is the Interval I=(-∞ , 3)

Is this correct? can someone help?

Comment: Are yoy trying to solve this inequality?

Comment: @SeanRoberson yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider where (x-3)(x-2)=0.  Then find where between or outside those points it is less than 0.

Comment: Is the answer(-∞, 3)

Comment: No.  Try x=-4, for example.

Comment: it's(1,3) right?

Comment: Where does the equation equal 0

Comment: okay it's (2,3)

Comment: Close, but why 1?

Comment: Yes.  That is right.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake

Comment: Welcome again. As you continue on, you'll likely have to consider unions of intervals. Consider, if this asked where x > 0.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow?

Comment: Sorry, misspoke. If your problem asked for which x the inequality is greater than 0.  (-$\infty$,2) $\cup$ (3,$\infty$)

Comment: is it possible that   I tag you and ask you a few more questions like throughout this week l, I have exams coming up and I have like zero help from anyone, it would be highly appreciated and if not also it's fine

Comment: Sure, but i work a ton, so am not always on here. If i am, i will help.

Comment: oh my god thank you so much it's fine please reply only when you're free! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem.  Good luck with learning for the exam.

Comment: hello, can you check out the question I've posted?